# Disable click on <a> tag when drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a carousel that contains  tags that link to details of movie. However, if you drag the mouse to rotate the carousel, when you drop it will redirect. How to prevent this?

[image: carousel]

I using ReactJs and my code look like:

```
   <Link
        to={"/detailfilm/" + data._id + "/" + data.title}
        draggable="false"
      >
      ...
   </Link>
```

Comment: You could technically use a variable to keep track of weather the carousel is in motion or not and allow the click even based on that, but I would more recommend using scroll wheel navigation than click and drag navigation as it's more accessible

Answer (score 2):

Create a class something like `disable` and add it while dragging and remove it  on drag end.

```css
.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```